# CLI looking/acting strange on a BeagleBone

Tags: 12.04, command-line, arm, auto-completion, su

I'm having an issue with the Command Line Interface. I'm running Precise 12.04 armhf on a BeagleBone and all the functionality works fine that I need. I have a 'cosmetic problem' when logged in as the non-default user. The command line is simply a "$" no matter what directory I'm on. When I'm logged in as the default user it reads "user@hostname/directory". Also autocomplete (tab completion) seems to be disabled when I'm using the other user. I can use 'su' and switch to and from the default username and get a different looking prompt ("$" and "user@hostname/directory"). Pretty sure it's an easy fix. Help!

Comment: could you run the command `echo $PS1` please? That will show what the prompt _should_ be

Comment: It comes back blank if that's what you mean.

Comment: hmmmmm very strange. try running `PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"`, does that fix the problem? (this will only be temporary)

Comment: it changes the prompt to ":+()}\u\@\h:\w$"

Comment: u=username h=hostname w=? I just put in a 'w'

Comment: Put in *exactly* what @jackweirdy said, *no substitutions!*

Comment: I did at first and it popped out exactly what I wrote down first.

Comment: Ensure double quotes are there :)

Comment: it's now \u@\h:\w$

Comment: PS1=\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

under the default username

Comment: I just recognized something. PS1 is "$" under the username giving me beef. It isn't blank.

Answer (score 1):

Answer found. I checked the /etc/passwd file and found that the shell for the user in question was /bin/sh not /bin/bash. Editing the shell fixed the issue.